# Hash an Array using initial values as keys and a block to generate key values

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Say I have an array:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

And I want to create a hash where each of these array elements is a key, and the value is the output of some block called with each of these elements as a block variable:

```
{ 1 => 4, 2 => 5, 3 => 6 }
```

I can do this using `map` and `to_h`:

```
a.map{ |n| [n, n + 3] }.to_h

#=> {1=>4, 2=>5, 3=>6}
```

Is there a single method that will do this? For example if it were called `hash_with`, I would be able to write:

```
a.hash_with{|n| n + 3}

#=> {1=>4, 2=>5, 3=>6}
```

Comment: Ruby, like most languages, supplies the building blocks to do these things. Packages like Rails build upon those building blocks to add icing on the cake. In your case, Ruby's "hash_with" is called `each_with_object`, only it works with all enumerables and lets you build new arrays or hashes or an arbitrary object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't (Ruby has a dearth of methods for turning Enumerables into Hashes), but it's pretty easy to write your own:

```
module Enumerable
  def hash_with
    each_with_object({}) {|elm, hsh| hsh[elm] = yield(elm) }
  end
end

[1,2,3].hash_with {|n| n + 3 }
# => { 1 => 4, 2 => 5, 3 => 6 }

('a'..'e').hash_with(&:upcase)
# => { "a" => "A", "b" => "B", "c" => "C", "d" => "D", "e" => "E" }

(:A..:E).hash_with { rand 100 }
# => { A: 28, B: 67, C: 58, D: 12, E: 20}
```

Comment: Two things.. first, I don't like is the name (not your fault:). How about `map_to_h`? Second, using `each_with_object` is likely a better implementation here as it doesn't create a temporary Array.

Comment: Those are good points, @KarolyHorvath. I've edited my answer to use `each_with_object`. `hash_with` isn't a great name, but I'm not sure `map_to_h` is any better.

Answer (score 5):

Look at [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object).

The documentation's example:

```
evens = (1..10).each_with_object([]) { |i, a| a << i*2 }
#=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

In that example they're using an array `[]` but you can just as easily use a hash using `{}` and stuff things into it:

```
hash = [1,2,3].each_with_object({}) { |i, h| h[i] = i + 3 } # => {1=>4, 2=>5, 3=>6}
```